# Low fps on Libgdx 3d

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx

I understand when dealing with fps the culprit here could be a number of things. But since I can't post my entire game here I'll give you the bullet points. Using libgdx and eclipse, along with adk I've built a top down shooter. I'm using all 3d models and no sprites at all. These models are medium to low Polly. On the desktop I get between 72 and 61 fps. On my Android emulator(1+gig ram, atom, gpu, etc) I'm getting around 34 - 20 fps... I've  analyzed the heap with mat and don't see anything to be alarmed about. I've also run the game and committed out the line of cod that actually renders thee models. Any ideas?

Also, there is this monster in my render loop, shes nasty, but what can I do?

```
for(int x = 0; x < ObjectLibrary.objects.size; x++){
            Object obj =  ObjectLibrary.objects.get(x);

            if(obj instanceof CameraContolObject){
                CameraContolObject cco = (CameraContolObject) obj;
                handleCameraContolObject(delta,cco);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof GameObjects){
                GameObjects gameObject = (GameObjects) obj;
                handleGameObject(delta, gameObject);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof Entity){
                Entity entity = (Entity) obj;
                handleEntity(delta, entity);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof Item){
                Item item = (Item) obj;
                handleItemObject(delta, item);
            }
            if(obj instanceof Bullet){
                Bullet bullet = (Bullet) obj;
                handleBullet(delta,bullet);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof Effect){
                Effect effect  = (Effect) obj;
                handleEffectObject(delta, effect);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof ModelInstance){
                ModelInstance model  = (ModelInstance) obj;
                handleModelInstance(delta, model);
            }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put them in different lists (of their actual subclass).

Comment: That's what I stared with. That produced a lower frame rate.

Comment: The emulator has a lot of odd performance characteristics, so I wouldn't do too much optimization based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The emulator has a lot of odd performance characteristics, so I wouldn't do too much optimization based on it. –  P.T. yesterday

Looks like you were right on the money. Without changing any code at all, i sent the APK file out to a few random friends and they reported that they were getting 55-61 fps.